# Create dadabase with spesific encoding from shell script

Tags: postgresql, scripting, encoding

I want to create a database from shell script, I add this line to my script

```
psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE template1 WITH OWNER = postgres ENCODING = 'LATIN1' TABLESPACE = pg_default LC_COLLATE = "fr_FR iso88591" LC_CTYPE = "fr_FR iso88591" CONNECTION LIMIT = -1 TEMPLATE template0;'
```

but I get the error `ERROR:  invalid locale name: "fr_FR iso88591"`

When I connect to postgresql then I run `CREATE DATABASE template1 WITH OWNER = postgres ENCODING = 'LATIN1' TABLESPACE = pg_default LC_COLLATE = "fr_FR iso88591" LC_CTYPE = "fr_FR iso88591" CONNECTION LIMIT = -1 TEMPLATE template0;` it works

What's the problem ? why I cannot create the database from shell script ?

Comment: You need to escape the embedded single quotes inside the single quotes. This is more a bash question (assuming you are using bash), not really a "DBA question"

Comment: I think it should be `fr_FR.iso88591` rather than `fr_FR iso88591` (if this is glibc). Otherwise, it looks fine.

Comment: the same problem